# R sweave don't print figure

Tags: r, latex

I'm using R Sweave, but r does not generate the figure. There may be a conflict in the packages or not. Which is the error.See line 73, in section * {Exercise I}, notice that in the chunk I am using fig = TRUE. Attached my code.

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, graphics, graphpap, layout, multicol, enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\geometry{verbose}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\hypersetup{bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,legalpaper,pagebackref,pdftitle=Parcial 1 Varias Variables,pdfauthor=Wilmer Pineda,pdfsubject=álgebra,pdfkeywords=álgebra}
\parindent=0pt
\definecolor {este}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{otro}{rgb}{0.56,0.65,0.76}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.93}
\renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{teo}[prop]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{cor}[prop]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[prop]{Lema}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definición}[section]
\newtheorem{ejem}{Ejemplo}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{nota}{Nota}
\newtheorem*{notac}{Notación}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablaqui}
  {\def\@captype{table}}
  {}
\newenvironment{figuraqui}
  {\def\@captype{figure}}
  {}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=80pt %para cambiar el tamaño del encabezado
\fancyhead[L] %la "L" indica a la izquierda
{
\begin{minipage}{2cm}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LogoEAN.eps}
\end{minipage}
}
\fancyhead[C] %la "C" indica al centro
{
\textbf
{Parcial 4}} %textsf es un tipo de letra

\fancyhead[R] %la "R" indica a la derecha
{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{flushright}
Wilmer Pineda\\
Fundamentos Sistemas Continuos Gr. 1\\
13 de Junio de 2017
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
}
%\title{\textbf{Parcial 2}}
%\author{Carlos Isaac Zainea\\ Álgebra Lineal \\ Universidad Francisco José de Caldas}
%\date{25 de Abril de 2013}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Este es un examen \textbf{individual}. No se permite el uso de libros, apuntes o cualquier medio electrónico. Los celulares deben estar \textbf{apagados} durante todo el examen. Las respuestas deben estar justificadas.

\section*{Ejercicio I}
Encuentre la longitud de la gráfica $x=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{y}(y-3)$ en el intervalo [1,9].

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Gráfica ejercicio 1.}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
 y=seq(1,9,0.01)
 x=(1/3)*sqrt(y)*(y-3)
 plot(x,y,type="l")
@
\end{figure}

\section*{Ejercicio II}
Encuentre el área de la superficie que se forma al girar la gráfica de $x=\frac{1}{3}(y^2+2)^{3/2}$ en el intervalo $1\leq y \leq 2$ alrededor del eje $x$.

\section*{Ejercicio III}
Calcular las coordenadas del centro de masa del área comprendida entre las parábolas $y^2=x$ y $x^2=-8y$.

\section*{Ejercicio IV}
Un tanque tiene la forma de un cono circular invertido con longitud $10m$ y radio de la base $4m$. Se llena de agua hasta una altura de $8m$. Encuentre el trabajo requerido para vaciar el tanque bombeando toda el agua a la parte superior del tanque.   (La densidad del agua es $1000kg/m^3$)

\section*{Ejercicio V}
Encuentre el volumen del sólido obtenida al girar la región comprendida entre $y=1+\sec(x)$ y $y=3$ alrededor de la recta $y=1$.

\section*{Ejercicio VI}
Las curvas de las funciones seno y coseno se intersecan infinitas veces, dando lugar a regiones de igual área. Calcular el área de una de dichas regiones.

\end{document}
```

To be specific this is the line that generates the error

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Gráfica ejercicio 1.}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
 y=seq(1,9,0.01)
 x=(1/3)*sqrt(y)*(y-3)
 plot(x,y,type="l")
@
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using .eps extension, so you should use the following code.

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Gráfica ejercicio 1.}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE, pdf=FALSE, eps=TRUE, png=TRUE>>=
y=seq(1,9,0.01)
x=(1/3)*sqrt(y)*(y-3)
plot(x,y,type="l")
@
\end{figure}
```